# Pandas map by index value without dummy column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame df with 100 rows and two columns, RowId and Probability. Now df is sorted in descending order according to Probability (e.g. 0.997, 0.973, 0.960, etc), and the index of df is in ascending order (0, 1, 2, etc).

I would like to map the values in the Probability column to 's' for 'success' for the first 10 values, and 'f' for 'fail' for the rest. To do this, I create a dummy column called Index, apply a transformation, and then drop the dummy column.

```
df['Index'] = range(0, 100)
df['Probability'] = df[['Probability', 'Index']].apply(lambda x:
                                                       's' if x['Index'] < 10
                                                       else 'f', axis=1)
df_result.drop(['Index'], axis=1)
```

Is there a way that I can do this **without** creating the dummy column?

Comment: based on ur code, u seem to attempt to assign fail to the first 10 items... wonder why thats the case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the index is already `0...n` then this would work:

```
df['Probability'] = np.where(df.index < 10, 's', 'f')
```

If you're not sure the index is in order, something like this?

```
 df.loc[df.index[:10], 'Probability'] = 's'
 df.loc[df.index[10:], 'Probability'] = 'f'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `iloc` it uses the actual location index as opposed to the index column:

```
a = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]], columns=['a','b'])
a['c'] = 'f'
>>> a
   a  b  c
0  1  2  f
1  3  4  f
2  5  6  f
3  7  8  f

a.iloc[0:2, a.columns.get_loc('c')] = 's'
>>> a
   a  b  c
0  1  2  s
1  3  4  s
2  5  6  f
3  7  8  f
```

The down side of `iloc` is that you can't provide column names as strings, you have to give their position as an int, which is why I use `a.columns.get_loc`.